# VBA Excel to Group data by Name

Tags: vba, excel

I'm not sure if this is possible with VBA.

I have this Data not in group: 
[image: Original Excel Table]

I need it to look like the following with "Module" grouped into Module 1,2,3, etc. and background color for the group: 
[image]
Please assist me with this in VBA.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you need VBA? This seems possible with a few Conditional Formatting rules. What have you tried so far?  Already I'm thinking of a rule `=C2-C1`  then set font to white (or yellow, or whatever) to hide duplicated data there. That way you can hide repetitive info, but keep actual info for running formulas/maths/`VLOOKUP()`/whatever...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also try Pivot Table to show the data in the format similar to that of your desired output.

Insert a Pivot Table and add all the fields in the Row area in the sequence as shown in the following image.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Sktneer. I didn't know that I can change the layout/design of Pivot Table like yours. As I know there is a way to generate a Pivot table like that with VBA, isn't it?